# How can I make the arrow paths more circular?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Here's what I have:

[image: an elliptical graph]

As you can see, the paths create an 'ellipse' around the two points, but I want a circle.

Here's my code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
                    thick]

  \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt);
  \filldraw[black] (0,3) circle (2pt);

  \path
    (0,0) edge [bend left, out=-90,in=-90] node[right] {$C_1$} (0,3)
    (0,0) edge [bend right, out=90,in=90] node[left] {$C_2$} (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I also would like to add arrows along the path, so it would look something like this at the end:
[image]

Comment: Well, use a `circle` if you want a circle …

Comment: hi, while that is true I can use circles, how can would I add the arrows onto the circles?

Comment: Zarko gave a nice solution using decorations, which would also be possible with a circle. In the end, this is actually what you're after, I think, since you want the arrow heads *on* the path and not only at the end, if I understood your question correctly. Alternatively, you could use the options `in` and `out` in combination with `looseness` to generate a path with a curvature close to a circle or an arc (`looseness=1.75` for example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb,
decoration={markings,% switch on markings
            mark=between positions 0.25 and 0.75 step 0.25 with {\arrow[thick]{>}},
            },
label distance = 3mm]

\draw[postaction={decorate}]   (0,0) arc (-90:90:1.5);
\draw[postaction={decorate}]   (0,0) arc (270:90:1.5);
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt);
\filldraw[black] (0,3) circle (2pt);
\coordinate[label=right:"$C_1$"] (c1) at ( 1.5,1.5);
\coordinate[label=left :"$C_2$"] (c2) at (-1.5,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Can you explain what exactly markings and the postaction functions are doing?

Comment: Have a look at the pgfmanual at ctan.org . There is a part dedicated to tikz libraries. Also postaction and decorate are most likely listed in the index: goto index and use search/find in your pdf reader.